# Angularjs datepicker set end date after start date

Tags: angularjs

I have problem with datepickers. When i choose start date it put end date to that start date, but when i try to change end date and open datepicker it stay on old date and then i need to move for example 6 months to choose date after start date. Is it possible to refresh datepicker for end date after selecting start date.

```
{
    key: 'startDate',
    type: 'horizontal-datepicker',
    templateOptions: {
        label: 'Start date',
        placeholder: $filter('translate')('Start date'),
        searchable: true
    }
},
{
    key: 'endDate',
    type: 'horizontal-datepicker',
    templateOptions: {
        label: 'End date',
        placeholder: $filter('translate')('End date'),
        searchable: true
    },
    minDate: 'model.startDate',
    controller: /* @ngInject */ function ($scope) {
        $scope.$watch('model.startDate', function (newValue, oldValue) {
            if(!newVal) return;

        // if the new start date is bigger than the current end date .. update the end date
        if($scope.model.endDate){
          if( +$scope.model.endDate < +$scope.model.startDate ){
            $scope.model.endDate = newVal;
          }
        } else {
          // just set the end date
          $scope.model.endDate = newVal;
        }
    }
},
```

detailed example:
if i as start date choose 12.July.2020 it set end date field to that date, but when i click on field to open datepicker in date picker it stayed on today date and then i must list all manual to the date 12.July.2020.
Is it possible to move it automatically to that date when i open datepicker for end date?